# disableOriginalConstructor() and will() conflict

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a model that uses DB adapter, that I want to test. The DB adapter's constructor deals with all the DB connection, so I would like to avoid it during testing, otherwise it returns errors with regards to db pass / db username etc not being set.

The code I'm currently running is below, as you see I'm using `disableOriginalConstructor()` to prevent calling the constructor.

The problem is that I'm getting this error, when I try to use `$mysql_stub` in `will()`:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker::will() must
>   implement interface PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub, instance of
>   Mock_Pages_MySQL_Page_46612429 given, called in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/lib/Pages/trunk/Tests/Unit/PageTest.php on
>   line 185 and defined

Could someone advise, what would the correct syntax be?

```
class Page {

  public function getByUrl($url)
  {
      $db_page = $this->getDAOInterface();
      $db_page->getByUrl($url);
      $this->assign($db_page);
      return $this;
  }

}

class PageTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testGetByUrl()
  {
      $test_url   = "foo-bar";
      $page_stub  = $this->getMock(
          'Pages_Model_Page', 
          array('getDAOInterface', 'assign')
      );

      $mysql_stub = $this->getMockBuilder('Pages_MySQL_Page')
                         ->setMethods(array('getByUrl'))
                         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                         ->getMock();

      $mysql_stub->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getByUrl')
                ->with($this->equalTo($test_url));

      $page_stub->expects($this->once())
                ->method('getDAOInterface')
                ->with()
                ->will($mysql_stub);

      $page_stub->expects($this->once())
                ->method('assign')
                ->with($mysql_stub);

      $page_stub->geByUrl($test_url);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out what was wrong with it. The error was caused by an omission on my part. The will should be invoked as per below:

```
$page_stub->expects($this->once())
          ->method('getDAOInterface')
          ->with()
          ->will($this->returnValue($mysql_stub));
```